# categorizing layouts and menu links in liferay

Tags: menu, navigation, liferay

I am installing layouts through the hook

with friendly url as follows

/cat1/link1, /cat1/link2

and

/cat2/link3, /cat2/link4

I want it insuch a way that when I navigate to cat1/link1

The nav links should be link1 and link2

and when i navigate to cat2/link3

The nav links should be link3 and link4

How can i achive this?

or can anyone suggest how can i group the layouts for multiple sites into different categories in same liferay install?

Thanks..

Comment: Do you use built in navigation portlet?

Comment: no .. I didnt use navigation portlet.. I am new to liferay .. can u tell what does that do?

Comment: How do you mean "I am installing layouts through the hook"? Do you mean control panel? And what do you mean by "when I navigate to cat1/link1 The nav links should be link1 and link2"?  Can you show urls?

Comment: no not control panel.. similar to 7 cogs hook.. we deploy a hook which will install the organization and the layouts associated during the liferay startup.. suppose my organization is org1 .. so my friendly url is org1/dashboard (eg).. so i want to display the menu links related to org1.. so similarly i want to create org2 and install layouts under it and display menu links accordingly.. I mean to say how to create multiple organizations in liferay.. sorry for the insufficient data in my question .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create organization (this is from seven-cogs `StartupAction.java`)

```java
long userId = defaultUserId;
long parentOrganizationId = OrganizationConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID;

String name = "7Cogs, Inc.";
String type = OrganizationConstants.TYPE_REGULAR_ORGANIZATION;

boolean recursable = true;
long regionId = 0;
long countryId = 0;
int statusId = GetterUtil.getInteger(PropsUtil.get("sql.data.com.liferay.portal.model.ListType.organization.status"));
String comments = null;

ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();

serviceContext.setAddCommunityPermissions(true);
serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);

Organization organization =
        OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization(
        userId, parentOrganizationId, name, type, recursable, regionId,
        countryId, statusId, comments, serviceContext);

Group group = organization.getGroup();
GroupLocalServiceUtil.updateFriendlyURL(group.getGroupId(), "/7cogs");
```

Are you sure that you need two organizations and not two communities?

UPDATE for question in comment:

To get organization name in theme (velovity) you can use (if you are in organization's pages (group))

In portal-ext.properties

```
journal.template.velocity.restricted.variables=
```

In theme vm file

Liferay 6

```
#set($os = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.OrganizationLocalService"))
#set($organization = $os.getOrganization($themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getOrganizationId()))
$organization.getName()
```

Liferay 5.x

```
#set($os = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.OrganizationLocalServiceUtil"))
#set($organization = $os.getOrganization($themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getOrganizationId()))
$organization.getName()
```

EDIT:

If your user is member of organization(s) than you can use

```
#foreach($org in $themeDisplay.getUser().getOrganizations())
    $org.getName()<br>
#end
```

Take note that user can be member of multiple organizations and you will get all of them.

Comment: yes .. I think i needs 2 diff organizations .. like 7 cogs.. one domain is completely diff than other

Comment: $organization.getName() prints as it is.. it doesnot print the organization name.. anything else i need to do?

Comment: if it is printed as it is than you are not in organization pages, you are probably probably in guest community. Try going to http://yourserver:port/web/organization_friendly_url. You also must set your theme to be used for organization pages. Let me know what happened, if it doesn't work we'll try somenthing else

Comment: its not in guest page.. The url is like /user/admin/org_name/dashboard ... I put the block of code you gave in navigation.vm.. I printed $themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getOrganizationId() .. it prints 0.

Comment: You are in user's (admin user) pages not organizations so it cannot work. I'll look for solution if you do indeed need organization name in user pages.

Comment: Thanks Martin.. yes .. This way i think its not going to work.. how about overriding servicepreaction.java and populating navitems accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

#### What you need to know about the code:

From the same class Martin mentioned I've put together a mix of code that will achieve what you need.

Note that some of the variables are not defined. You'll have to use the correct values that are particular to your Liferay installation. For example, the userId could be anyone but I would suggest using either the default user's userId or an administrator's userId.

#### The Code:

```java
Organization organization =
    OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization(
        userId, OrganizationConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_ORGANIZATION_ID,
        "My Org 1", OrganizationConstants.TYPE_REGULAR_ORGANIZATION, true,
        regionId, countryId, statusId, comments, true, serviceContext);

Group group = organization.getGroup();

GroupLocalServiceUtil.updateFriendlyURL(group.getGroupId(), "/cat1");

LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout(
    group.getCreatorUserId(), group.getGroupId(), "false",
    LayoutConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_LAYOUT_ID, "My Link 1", StringPool.BLANK,
    StringPool.BLANK, LayoutConstants.TYPE_PORTLET, false, "/link1",
    false, serviceContext);

LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout(
    group.getCreatorUserId(), group.getGroupId(), "false",
    LayoutConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_LAYOUT_ID, "My Link 2", StringPool.BLANK,
    StringPool.BLANK, LayoutConstants.TYPE_PORTLET, false, "/link2",
    false, serviceContext);

organization =
    OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.addOrganization(
        userId, parentOrganizationId, name, type, recursable, regionId,
        countryId, statusId, comments, true, serviceContext);

group = organization.getGroup();

GroupLocalServiceUtil.updateFriendlyURL(group.getGroupId(), "/cat2");

LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout(
    group.getCreatorUserId(), group.getGroupId(), "false",
    LayoutConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_LAYOUT_ID, "My Link 3", StringPool.BLANK,
    StringPool.BLANK, LayoutConstants.TYPE_PORTLET, false, "/link3",
    false, serviceContext);

LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout(
    group.getCreatorUserId(), group.getGroupId(), "false",
    LayoutConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_LAYOUT_ID, "My Link 4", StringPool.BLANK,
    StringPool.BLANK, LayoutConstants.TYPE_PORTLET, false, "/link4",
    false, serviceContext);
```

Comment: suppose if user belong to both organization .. he sees both organizations links.. i want to categorize on friendly url

Comment: let me make it clear .. for each user we are adding private layouts ..  as you told i added few layouts to org1 and few to org2 and added the same layouts of each user so that user has access to both the organization.. once i go to org1/link1 .. i seee all the links org1+org2.. I need it decide based on friendly url.. any idea??

Comment: Is it possible to get organization name in theme velocity template